# AppWarp Unity SDK fails to connect with CONNECTION_ERROR error

Tags: unity-game-engine, appwarp

I'm running into this basic issue while integrating the AppWarp Unity SDK (no version is specified, downloaded on 10 of March) with Unity 4.3.4 Android player.
The AppWarpVikingMobile sample fails with the same error.
"telnet appwarp.shephertz.com 12346" does connect to the server. Wireshark shows no packets (running with a filter "host appwarp.shephertz.com").

There is a similar issue asked here on February, but it is unresolved still.
Seems that it's SDK import/compatibility issue.
Any ideas?

Comment: Well, I've just imported AppWarpUnity.dll instead of AppWarpUnityMobile.dll and got the stable connection.
So does it mean that I need to import various DLL's when running the Unity Editor and running the app on a mobile device? It does not sound reasonable, is there other way to handle the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When running in the player you have to use the **AppWarpUnity.dll** asset. Its only when building the apk to run on a physical device you need to build with **AppWarpUnityMobile.dll** asset (and *NOT AppWarpUnity.dll*) along with the native plugins provided.

It can be a bit confusing because Unity has different restrictions on different versions (Pro and Free) for different platforms with regards to plugins and sockets. AppWarp's goal is to give developers a way to use it with or without the Unity Pro on all platforms.

The interface exposed by the assets is the same so your application code need not change.

Comment: You can also read the intro blog post for this feature on shephertz blog here http://blogs.shephertz.com/2014/02/03/appwarp-support-for-android-and-ios-build-from-unity-free/

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. What I need to do in order "only when building the apk to run on a physical device you need to build with AppWarpUnityMobile.dll asset"? Should I remove AppWarpUnity.dll and import AppWarpUnityMobile.dll before the building? If so, I'll need to remove AppWarpUnityMobile.dll and import again the AppWarpUnity.dll when running with the editor after that?

Comment: Yes. You'll need to remove AppWarpUnity.dll asset when building for mobile. Replace that with AppWarpUnityMobile.dll. Similarly when building for player, remove AppWarpUnityMobile.dll and replace with AppWarpUnity.dll... The plugins folder can be left there as Unity is smart enough to pick it only when required.